# rosdep install error

Tags: ros, rosdep, cartographer, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install `cartographer_ros`. I was following the "Building and installation" instruction provided in [here](http://google-cartographer-ros.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) .
At one step when I tried

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro=${ROS_DISTRO} -y
```

I got following error.

```
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
laser_geometry: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [pcl]
spin_hokuyo: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [pcl]
```

FYI, I use `pcl_ros`, `laser_geometry` in my workspace as I have modified them for my application.

I am not very sure what is the source of this error.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/289266/rosdep-install-error/) by [Spartan_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/21890/spartan_007/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2018-04-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I am not very sure what is the source of this error.

`pcl` is not a valid rosdep key, which is why `rosdep` cannot find it.

The keys for PCL itself are [libpcl-all-dev](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/2f6413b647bdcefb00f8ff17890609ae6e6cbbaf/rosdep/base.yaml#L2411-L2433) (build depend) and [libpcl-all](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/2f6413b647bdcefb00f8ff17890609ae6e6cbbaf/rosdep/base.yaml#L2385-L2410) (run depend), but it's more common to depend on the ROS wrapper packages which will bring in PCL as one of their dependencies. For that, just depend on the ROS package names (ie: `pcl_conversions` and friends).

Note that this is not a problem with/in Cartographer, but in `spin_hokuyo` and your copy of `laser_geometry`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Spartan_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/21890/spartan_007/) on 2018-04-21**:
cool. I removed the build dependency on `PCL` from both the packages and it works.  thanks.